# Flutter: setState inside Build

Tags: http, flutter, build, setstate

I want to fetch data from the Internet, so I use a function named getNumData and placed it in the Build function. The getNumData function uses http.get to fetch data, and then store it after decoded. Here comes the problem. I have to call setState to store the data (set the Numdata List to the data I just fetched). But if I do so, it becomes a "setState called during Build" error. This is kind of an awkward situation. What can I do to reslove the problem? Thanks for instance.

The Build function:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final key = utf8.encode(AppKey);
    final hmac = hmacSha1(key, utf8.encode(SignDate));
    final base64HmacString = base64Encode(hmac);

    final Authorization = "hmac username=\"" + AppID + "\", algorithm=\"hmac-sha1\", headers=\"x-date\", signature=\"" + base64HmacString + "\"";

    getNumData();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < Numdata.length ; i++){
      if(Numdata[i]['stationName'] == DStation){
        DStationNum = Numdata[i]['stationCode'];
        break;
      }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < Numdata.length ; i++){
      if(Numdata[i]['stationName'] == AStation){
        AStationNum = Numdata[i]['stationCode'];
        break;
      }
    }



    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(191, 62, 255, 1),
        title: Text('火車查詢'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getTableData(Authorization, xdate, DStationNum, AStationNum),
          builder: (context, snap){
            if(!snap.hasData){
              return Container();
            }
            List<dynamic> datas = [];
            datas = jsonDecode(snap.data.body);
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: datas.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return ListTile(title: Text(datas[index]['DailyTrainInfo']["TrainTypeName"]["Zh_tw"] + '      ' + datas[index]['OriginStopTime']["DepartureTime"] + '   =>   ' + datas[index]['DestinationStopTime']["DepartureTime"]), subtitle: Text(datas[index]['DailyTrainInfo']["TrainNo"]),);
              },
            );
          }),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: onTabTapped,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex, // this will be set when a new tab is tapped
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.school),
            title: new Text('大學'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.directions_subway),
            title: new Text('交通'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.person),
            title: new Text('個人'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

The getNumData function:

```
getNumData() async{
    final String hostNum = 'http://ods.railway.gov.tw/tra-ods-web/ods/download/dataResource/0518b833e8964d53bfea3f7691aea0ee';
    final response = await http.get(hostNum);
    setState(() {
      Numdata = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
    });
  }
```

Comment: First, do not call API under build method. Call it initially (in the initState). Build gets called whenever you do setState, which will again fetch the data and do setState, hence indulged in an infinite loop. @HoshiChen

Comment: Thanks! I'll take note of it and make sure to remember next time!! @Pushpendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to resolve this could be is to move all this logic

```
getNumData();
for(int i = 0 ; i < Numdata.length ; i++){
  if(Numdata[i]['stationName'] == DStation){
    DStationNum = Numdata[i]['stationCode'];
    break;
  }
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < Numdata.length ; i++){
  if(Numdata[i]['stationName'] == AStation){
    AStationNum = Numdata[i]['stationCode'];
    break;
  }
}
```

inside `getTableData`. So your `getTableData` method would be converted to

```
//DStationNum and  AStationNum won't be passed as parameter since they will be calculated inside
Future<...> getTableData(...) async { 
    await getNumData();
    for(int i = 0 ; i < Numdata.length ; i++){
      if(Numdata[i]['stationName'] == DStation){
        DStationNum = Numdata[i]['stationCode'];
        break;
      }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < Numdata.length ; i++){
      if(Numdata[i]['stationName'] == AStation){
        AStationNum = Numdata[i]['stationCode'];
        break;
      }
    }

    ....
}
```